# element-wise multiplication - 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, layer

It's a problem with code of Keras using Tensorflow.

I have a simple network where I need to do an element-wise multiplication immediately after the input. This part of code is shown below. I always got the error:

*** AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'

My code:

```
    input_img = Input(shape=(256, 256, 2, 1, 2))
    masked = Lambda(lambda x: tf.multiply(x[0], x[1]))([input_img[:,:,:,:,:,0], input_img[:,:,:,:,:,1]])
    conv1 = Conv3D(1, (5, 5, 2), padding='same',  activation=activation, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(1e-9))(masked)
    net_head = Model(inputs=input_img, outputs=conv1)
```

I already used Lambda layer, so I'm confused which caused this problem. The dimension of the input fits well the model, so this should not the problem.

Does anyone have a clue?

This element-wise multiplication is actually to mask some pixels into zeros. In the code above, the mask is concatenated in the additional last dimension in to the input variable. 
Alternatively, I also tried using a variable exclusive for the mask, e.g. input_mask, instead of including it as an additional last dimension in the input_image, to do the multiplication, which didn't work either with the same error info.

The reason I have to do the masking process on the input data after the input layer of the network, instead of before the input layer, is that I need the complete data (including the being masked) of the input image in loss computation with shuffle on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are operating your tensors outside of a layer. (Getting slices are operations too)

You would need to take the slices `input_img[:,:,:,:,:,0]` and `input_img[:,:,:,:,:,1]` **inside** a layer.

```
masked = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,:,:,:,:,0]*x[:,:,:,:,:,1])(input_img)
```

Comment: Great, @user2789986. When an answer solves your problem, please mark it as answered :)

Answer (score 1):

As [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53744191/1782792) pointed out, you cannot take slices out of a layer, because that generates "raw" tensors without the annotations that Keras uses. If you still want to have the two-input layer for some reason, you can just encapsulate the slices into layers as well:

```
input_img = Input(shape=(256, 256, 2, 1, 2))
slice0 = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, :, :, :, :, 0])(input_img)
slice1 = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, :, :, :, :, 1])(input_img)
masked = Lambda(lambda x: tf.multiply(x[0], x[1]))([slice0, slice1])
net_head = Model(inputs=input_img, outputs=masked)
# ...
```

Comment: Thanks! This will be helpful when I use the mask as a separate variable.